# Error running Azure Pipeline using Bicep File

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

ERROR: Error while attempting to download Bicep CLI: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>

I can run it using the az cli from local machine but I get error using Azure Pipelines.

ERROR: Error while attempting to download Bicep CLI: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>

I can run it using the az cli from local machine but I get error using Azure Pipelines.

Simple Pipeline

```
trigger: none

pool: poolname

variables:
  - name: deploymentDefaultLocation
    value: eastus2

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    connectedServiceName: JNF-NPRD-SC-31305-JNF-CNF-DEV22
    deploymentName: $(Build.BuildNumber)
    location: $(deploymentDefaultLocation)
    resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroupName)
    csmFile: deploy/main.bicep
    overrideParameters: >
      -environmentType $(EnvironmentType)
      -deployjnfcManualsStorageAccount $(DeployjnfcManualsStorageAccount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code '403'indicates it's a permission error. Please confirm the service principal(created with ARM service connection `JNF-NPRD-SC-31305-JNF-CNF-DEV22`) has enough permission on the target resource group and storageaccount.

In addition, do you have network/firewall setting on the resources? If yes, check the agent(`pool: poolname` it appears you are using self-hosted agent) ip is in the network whitelist or you can temporarily disable the network/firewall setting for a try.

In addition, you can try [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/add-template-to-azure-pipelines?tabs=CLI#deploy-bicep-files) instead to deploy with the bicep file, it could help to narrow down the issue.